# Annotation to show Entity's property description - using nelmioapidocbundle

Tags: symfony, serialization, annotations, entity

I am using nelmioapidocbundle in order to documents my Rest API built on the top of  symfony-2.x.

I can't found the right annotation to use to show each Entity's property description on the return section (Please see bellow attached image).

My Entity :

```
/**
 * Checkins
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="CheckIns")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Project1\ApiBundle\Entity\CheckinsRepository")
 *
 * @ExclusionPolicy("none")
 */
class Checkins
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     *
     * @Groups({"checkin"})
     * @
     */
    private $id;
```

My Controller :

```
 class CheckinController extends BaseRestController
 {
    /**
     * @ApiDoc(
     *  resource=true,
     *  description="Find checkin by ID",
     *
     * parameters={
     *      {"name"="categoryId", "dataType"="integer", "required"=true, "description"="checkin id"}
     *  }
     *
     *  output={
     *      "class"="Project1\ApiBundle\Entity\Checkins",
     *      "groups"={"checkin"}
     *  },
     *  statusCodes={
     *      200="Checkin found",
     *      400="ID is required",
     *      404="Checkin not found"
     *  }
     * )
     *
     * @Rest\View()
     */
    public function getAction(Request $request)
    {}
```

Result ( Description column is empty ) :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a description in doc section of the bundle:

> For classes parsed with JMS metadata, description will be taken from the properties doc comment, if available.
>   For Form Types, you can add an extra option named description on each
>   field

Please visit the following link for more instructions(info at the bottom of the section):

https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#the-apidoc-annotation